# @Resource private WebServiceContext context is giving null value

Tags: web-services, tomcat

I am trying to take `ServletContext` in my web service ,but `WebServiceContext` is always `NULL`.Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong, I am using spring framework and tomcat.

```
package com.xyz.webser;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@WebService(serviceName = "myWebService", endpointInterface = "com.xyz.webser.MyWebService")
public class MyWebServiceImpl implements MyWebService {

  @Resource
  private WebServiceContext context;

  public void setContext(WebServiceContext context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new java file in service package used "implements ServletContextAware"
called that method from web service.